# Reference request: Proof that second cohomology of loop algebra is 1-dimensional

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra. Define its loop algebra $L(\mathfrak{g})=\mathfrak{g}[t,t^{-1}]$ as the space of Laurent series of finite length with values in $\mathfrak{g}$. A typical element of $L(\mathfrak{g})$ is hence of the form $a(t) = \sum_{i}a_it^{i}$. Its derivative is denoted by $a'(t)$. The following is a standard theorem:

**Theorem 1.** The second cohomology of $L(\mathfrak{g})$ is 1-dimensional and is spanned by the 2-cocycle
$$\alpha(a(t), b(t)) = Res_{t=0}(\langle a'(t), b(t)\rangle).$$

**Question.** Where can I find a reference that goes through the proof of this? The references I've been able to find so far only sketch out the proof or leave it as an exercise altogether.

Comment: What is the module for the cohomology? [Here](https://books.google.at/books?id=WNYZfKpCHFMC&pg=PA343&lpg=PA343&dq=second+cohomology+of+loop+algebra+is+1-dimensional&source=bl&ots=BITbKFHFZg&sig=ACfU3U2CvWIozLwhuJGum9RUT3W8SXBrGA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRzPy6qa7pAhXQ2qQKHdk3CfMQ6AEwAnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=second%20cohomology%20of%20loop%20algebra%20is%201-dimensional&f=false) we learn that $H^2_0(L(\mathfrak{g}),\Bbb R)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Taking $\mathbb{C}$ as the module of the (algebraic) cohomology.